# How can I animate items of an array in JSX

Tags: css-animations, jsx, stenciljs

I have a list of chats in an array, that is updated live, when a user chats with a chatbot.
When a new message arrives, the newest message is moved to the top.

I now want to animate this behaviour. Does anybody know, how I can add a animation or transition to the element, that is moved to the top?

My Component:

```
import { Component, h, Prop } from '@stencil/core';
import { BotUserModel } from '../../global/models/BotUserModel';
import { ChatCategory } from '../../global/models/ChatCategory';

@Component({
  tag: 'chathub-pool-column',
  styleUrl: 'pool-column.scss',
  shadow: true,
})
export class PoolColumn {
  @Prop()
  category: ChatCategory;

  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.category.title}>
        <p>{this.category.title} | {this.category.chats.length}</p>
        <div>
          {this.category.chats.map((botUser: BotUserModel) => (
            <div key={botUser._id}
              class={
                'card text-white bg-primary mb-3 p-2 poolCard rounded-0'
              }
            >
              <div class={'card-header'}>{botUser._id}</div>
              <div class={'card-body d-flex flex-row ' +
              'justify-content-between align-items-center'}>
                <span class={'w-100 mr-2'}>
                  {botUser.incomingMessages.length > 0
                    ? botUser.incomingMessages[
                    botUser.incomingMessages.length - 1
                      ].text
                    : 'No message has arrived'}
                </span>
                <i class={'fa-plus'} />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

[Here is how this looks in the Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CfM8.png)

EDIT:

To clarify: My ideal solution would be, that the chat with the newest Message moves to the top, while the other entries go one step lower. Like you would sort a list per drag and drop. My initial idea was to use CSS-Transitions, but I don't know which attribute to listen on in this case.

With some help/inspiration of Christian (see comments) I made a simple blink effect that triggers, when a new message arrives.

```
.blink {
  animation: pulse .5s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

The code Method in the component (I changed the initial code quite a bit."this.card" refers to the div, that is created with this.category.chats.map)

```
  @Watch('timestamp')
  handleTextChange() {
    this.card.classList.add('blink');
    this.card.onanimationend = () => {
      this.card.classList.remove('blink');
    };
  }
```

This is fine, but if you have an idea, how I could achieve my ideal solution, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a CSS animation. In my point of view that is the most easiest way to achieve an animation that doesn't mess up your code. Sadly I can't see your CSS properties and I'm not sure which of your classes is suitable for this but my idea would be something like:

```
.card {
  /*Your properties*/

  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;

  /*Your properties*/
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 0%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

But as I mentioned above - that depends a on your already written CSS.
A really good website in my opinion to get a real quick start for ready to use animations would be this:

https://animista.net/play/entrances

> Addition

I think it's not necessary in your case but you can run the animations one by one:

```
  {this.category.chats.map((botUser: BotUserModel, index) => (
    <div key={botUser._id}
      class={
        'card text-white bg-primary mb-3 p-2 poolCard rounded-0'
      }
      style={{'animation-delay': index+'s'}}
    >
```

So the two differences are using the index of the map function and than using inline style tag with the animation delay. The first one has 1s delay, second 2s delay and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and especially for the animista recommendation. I was however mostly looking for a way to transition a card to the top. Do you have an idea for this? 
I can probably make something good with your suggestion, but I would prefer the transition approach

Comment: I'm sure I can help you and can produce the exact result you are looking for. But in order to do so I need more information of what you already have and what you would like to achieve. Do you want the latest message to fly in from the top of the screen? Do you want the message to diverge from the bottom to the top? Maybe you can take a few more minutes to add more details to your question and always remember, the more details you give us, the better we can help you. :- )